# Deducir this (C++23)

Tags: c++, c++23

He querido probar la característica de deducir `this` de C++23 con el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

struct S
{
    auto &operator[](this S &s, size_t index)
    {
        return s.xyz[index];
    }

    auto begin(this S &s)
    {
        return begin(s.xyz);
    }

    auto end(this S &s)
    {
        return end(s.xyz);
    }
private:
    int xyz[3]{};
};

int main()
{
    S a;
    const S b;

    // Correcto, llama a operator[] con 'this = a', devuelve 'int &'.
    a[1] = 1;
    // Correcto, llama a begin/end con 'this = a'
    for (auto &v : a)
        cout << v << ' ';

    // Fallo 1: Llama a operator[] con 'this = b', falla porque devuelve 'const int &' que no es modificable.
    b[2] = 2;
    // Fallo 2: Falla, pero ¿Por qué?
    for (auto &v : b)
        cout << v << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Los errores que estoy recibiendo no cuadran con el comportamiento que creía que debía tener esta característica, en el `Fallo 1` el error es:

> ```
> error C2678: binary '[': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const S' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
> ```

Entendía que en la función `auto &operator[](this S &s, size_t index)` cuando la instancia era constante (`const S`) `this` se deducía como constante así que el error debería haber sido que *no se puede asignar valor a `const int &`*.

En el `Fallo 2` el error es:

> ```
> error C2664: '_Ty *S::begin(S &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const S' to 'S &'
> error C2664: '_Ty *S::end(S &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const S' to 'S &'
> ```

De nuevo creía que `this` se habría deducido como constante, así que no entiendo por qué se muestra el error.

Parece que estoy entendiendo mal esta nueva característica ¿Por qué no se deduce `this` como constante cuando se llama pasando una instancia constante?

Comment: Qué compilador estás usando? gcc parece no tener esa característica aún.

Comment: [Sólo está soportado en MSVC 19.3 y ecpp 6.3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23), por cierto ya he encontrado en qué me equivoqué.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El parámetro `this` de la funcionalidad de C++23 "*deducir `this`*" no autodeduce el cualificador `const`, necesitas definir dos funciones diferentes para eso:

```
// Versión de operator[] para cuando la instancia es constante 'this const S'
auto &operator[](this const S &s, size_t position)
{
    return s.xyz[position];
}
// Versión de operator[] para cuando la instancia NO es constante 'this S'
auto &operator[](this S &s, size_t position)
{
    return s.xyz[position];
}
```

La manera de evitar duplicar código usando la deducción de `this` es usando plantillas:

```
// T se deduce como 'const S' al llamarse sobre instancias constantes
// y se deduce como 'S' al llamarse sobre instancias no constantes
template <typename T>
auto &operator[](this T &t, size_t position)
{
    return t.xyz[position];
}

// T se deduce como 'const S' al llamarse sobre instancias constantes
// y se deduce como 'S' al llamarse sobre instancias no constantes
template <typename T>
auto begin(this T &t)
{
    return std::begin(t.xyz);
}

// T se deduce como 'const S' al llamarse sobre instancias constantes
// y se deduce como 'S' al llamarse sobre instancias no constantes
template <typename T>
auto end(this T &t)
{
    return std::end(t.xyz);
}
```

Comment: Me parece bien que sea así. Para hacer lo mismo sin esta característica necesitas 2 versiones del método, una marcada como const y la otra no. Aunque ahora se puede simplificar con plantillas gracias a `this`.

Comment: Precisamente esa es la motivación de este cambio, según el [P0847](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html), la respuesta la tenía en ese documento pero lo leí mal.