# ¿Por qué no funciona los metodos begin y end en C++?

Tags: c++

Tengo una clase Notas que almacena n notas en un vector y para recorrer el vector implemente los metodos begin y end.

```
class Notas{
    std::vector<int> notas_;
public:
    Notas(const int size){
        notas_.resize(size);
    }
    auto begin(){
        return notas_.begin();
    }
    auto end(){
        return notas_.end();
    }
};
```

Y cuando hago un recorrido sobre los elementos va todo bien, puedo modificar y leer sin problemas.

```
int main(){
    Notas notas(3);
    int contador{};

    // asigna notas
    for(auto &nota : notas){
        nota = ++contador;
    }

    // muestra notas
    for(auto &nota : notas){
        std::cout<<nota<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pero si me llevo la logica de mostrar a una funcion me da error en el IDE.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funcion mostrar:

```
void mostrar(const Notas &notas){
    for(auto &nota : notas){
        std::cout<<nota<<"\n";
    }
}
```

el ide me marca que el error esta en `notas` de dentro de los parentesis del for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es porque también debes implementar ambas funciones pero para referencias constantes. Así:

```
auto begin() const {
    return notas_.begin();
}
auto end() const {
    return notas_.end();
}
```

En teoría si usas [*this deducido*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/587784/169744) no es necesario.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no se solucionó el error.

Comment: error mio!, si que funciona, no me di cuenta de que los nombres de los metodos constantes son iguales a los no constantes.

Answer (score 2):

Primero, faltaba poner el guión_bajo en el nombre la declaración del vector notas_.
Segundo, en la definición de mostrar() hay que poner un nombre que va a ser una referencia al objeto de la clase Notas. Después accedes al miembro notas_ con el operador punto en el bucle for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Notas{
    public:
    std::vector<int> notas_;

    Notas(const int size){
        notas_.resize(size);
    }
    auto begin(){
        return notas_.begin();
    }
    auto end(){
        return notas_.end();
    }
};

void mostrar(const Notas & unNombreQueHaceReferenciaAlObjeto){
    for(auto &nota : unNombreQueHaceReferenciaAlObjeto.notas_){
        std::cout<<nota<<"\n";
    }
}

int main(){
    Notas notas(3);
    int contador{};

    // asigna notas
    for(auto &nota : notas){
        nota = ++contador;
    }

    // muestra notas
    for(auto &nota : notas){
        std::cout<<nota<<"\n";
    }

    mostrar(notas);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, entiendo lo que propones, pero no es aconsejable exponer la lógica interna de una clase, en mi caso solo me interesa que el usuario pueda fijar el número de notas que quiere almacenar y recorrerlas (diseño/propósito), pero si pongo el vector como publico el usuario puede hacer muchas cosas más con él y eso no es lo que quiero porque rompería el diseño/propósito de mi clase.